# Need to use java script function on fields of two forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hey all I need to use java script function to validate fields of two form.
Basically the criteria is when user select form name then the require fields has to be visible on next form.. I need to ask that if I can use java script function for forms on different pages. Below is my code

code for form rpt

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/formvalidations.js"></script>
</head>
<form name="rpt" method="post" action="">
    <label>Form Name </label>
    <select id="formname" name="formname"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please Select Form Name--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select><br />
<input id="ok" type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" onclick="return chkform();" />
</form>
</html>
```

code for java script function

```
function chkform(){
    var formname = document.forms.rpt.formname.value;
        if (formname == "1"){
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("1").style.display="inline";
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("2").style.display="inline";
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("3").style.display="inline"
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("4").style.display="none";
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("5").style.display="none";

        }
        elseif (formname == "2"){
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("1").style.display="inline";
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("2").style.display="none";
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("3").style.display="inline"
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("4").style.display="none";
            document.forms.reportform.getElementById("5").style.display="inline";
        }
        else{
            alert("select form name");
            return false;
        }
}
```

I have 5 fields in form reportform. and I need required fields to be visible in reportform. lets say if user select value 1 in rpt then field 1, 2 and 3 has to be visible.

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting an error, or does that code not do what you expect? (You didn't actually ask a question.)

Comment: yeah that code not do what I expect, on reportform I am getting all the fields visible. :(

Comment: Numbers as `id` are not valid before HTML5, no doctype on your code? Also you know you can do `var report = document.forms.reportform` and will be faster and cleaner.

Comment: @elclanrs thanks for your help. lots of appreciations :)

Comment: Could you please update your question to show `reportForm`? Is it on the same page?

Comment: @nnnnnn I have reportform on another page named reportform.html

Comment: that's what I need to ask apologies if I ask something irrelevant. please can u guide me according to my quires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a syntax error on this line:

```
elseif (formname == "2"){
```

JavaScript doesn't have `elseif` as a single word, you need to insert a space:

```
else if (formname == "2"){
```

Also, the [`getElementById()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) is a method of `document`, not of individual html elements, so use:

```
document.getElementById("1").style.display="inline";
// and so forth
```

If you use your browser's JS console (e.g., in Chrome press F12) it will report these errors to you (it won't tell you how to fix them, but at least it'll point you in the right direction).

Comment: Please update your code with my suggestions, and take Ashwin's suggestion to change your OK button to `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`, and then let us know if you still have problems.

Comment: I checked by changing submit to button but now it doesn't take me to reportform.html

Comment: Yes, sorry, I assumed your second form was on the same page. Even aside from the JavaScript errors I pointed out, JavaScript can only manipulate fields on the current page. It would be better to do the conditional display with server-side code, i.e., with PHP (as in Ashwin's answer) or JSP, ASP, or whatever you're using.

Comment: I'm using php for all this stuff.